# How to continue lines on next page in exam class \fillwithdottedlines

Tags: exam

My question is basically the same question as this one previously asked:

[How to continue lines on next page in exam class \fillwithlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351108/how-to-continue-lines-on-next-page-in-exam-class-fillwithlines)

Except its for \fillwithdottedlines

"I use the exam class to typeset my exams. I usually leave space for answers with \fillwithdottedlines{3in} because I prefer to fix the amount of space. However, when a question is at the end of a page and the space required by \fillwithdottedlines{3in} exceeds it, the lines do not continue on the next page. Instead, the entire question is moved to the next page while the current page is blank space. Is there a way to change that behavior and have lines starting on one page and then continue on the next."

Any help would be appreciated :D.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This question should appear on page 1. It should be followed by lines which continue on page 2.
\fillwithdottedlines{20in}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change yours lines of code with this once:

```
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This question should appear on page 1. It should be followed by lines which continue on page 2.
        \fillwithlines{2in}
        \item Second question.
        \fillwithlines{4in}
        \item Third question.
        \fillwithlines{3in}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and you have:

[image]