# Number lines in fillwithlines command from exam package

Tags: macros, exam

I would like to add the line number of each line instead of the character "a" which I managed to add by tweaking the code a bit.

The code is already modified according to [How to continue lines on next page in exam class \fillwithlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351108/how-to-continue-lines-on-next-page-in-exam-class-fillwithlines) in order for the lines to span over multiple pages.

Here is the code at the moment:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\linefillheight
\newlength\linefillthickness
\setlength\linefillheight{.25in}
\setlength\linefillthickness{0.1pt}

\newcommand{\linefill}[1]{\leavevmode
   #1 \leaders\hrule height \linefillthickness \hfill\kern\z@}


\def\fillwithlines#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \linefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
          \linefill{a}}%
  % We use \cleaders (rather than \leaders) so that a given
  % vertical space will always produce the same number of lines
  % no matter where on the page it happens to start:
  %\cleaders \copy0 \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
    \loop\ifdim\dimen0<#1\relax
    \advance\dimen0 by \ht0
    \copy0\space
  \repeat
      \endgroup
}

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works. I defined a counter and printed the counter before the each line incrementing it.

I also changed the code so that the fillwithlines command becomes of function of the number of lines to print and not of the vertical space of lines wanted.

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\linefillheight
\newlength\linefillthickness
\setlength\linefillheight{.25in}
\setlength\linefillthickness{0.1pt}

\newcommand{\linefill}{\leavevmode \leaders\hrule height \linefillthickness \hfill\kern\z@}
\newcounter{linecounter}
\setcounter{linecounter}{0}

\def\fillwithlines#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \linefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
          \linefill}%
  % We use \cleaders (rather than \leaders) so that a given
  % vertical space will always produce the same number of lines
  % no matter where on the page it happens to start:
  %\cleaders \copy0 \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
    \loop\ifnum\thelinecounter<#1\relax
    \addtocounter{linecounter}{1}
    \thelinecounter
    \advance\dimen0 by \ht0
    \copy0\space
  \repeat
      \endgroup
}
```

Comment: But it is an answer, how should I do it?

Comment: @Nre: Does this answer the/your question, or was it meant as an addition to the question? (...just clarifying...)